# Testing Bad Request while posting an incomplete entity with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-rest, spring-rest, mockmvc

I'm trying to test the creation of an entity with incomplete data as follows:

```
@Test
public void postVisitor_withIncompleteData_shouldFailWithBadRequest() throws Exception {
    Visitor emptyVisitor = new Visitor();

    mockMvc.perform(post("/visits")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(visitor))
            ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

But my test fails with this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.reweb.Visitor] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='cannot be empty', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.reweb.Visitor, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]
```

How can I test this is a bad request?

Adding `@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)` wouldn't work either.

Comment: You might not have binded the validator in the controller. Do you have this in your controller      @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(constraintValidator);
    }

Comment: I think, you need to show code for `Visitor` and how you using `@Valid` or `@Validated`. `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` doesn't automatically handle - `ConstraintViolationException` .

Answer (score 1):

If you have already configured @Valid with @ResponseBody in controller , then you need to create ExceptionHandlerInterceptor just like below:

```
    @RestControllerAdvice
    @Slf4j
    public class ApplicationExceptionInterceptor extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver {

      @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
      public
        ResponseEntity<Response<?>>
        handleControllerException(final HttpServletRequest request, final Throwable ex) {

        if (ex instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException) {
          log.error(ex.getMessage());
          final MethodArgumentNotValidException exception = (MethodArgumentNotValidException) ex;
          final List<ObjectError> errors = exception.getBindingResult().getAllErrors();
          final List<FaultDetail> faultDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
          final List<String> error = new ArrayList<>();
          errors.forEach(action -> error.add(action.getDefaultMessage()));
          faultDetailsList.add(new FaultDetail(error));

        }
return ResponseEntity.body(faultList).status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
}
```

You also need to provide to provide this ExceptionHandler to MockMvc just like below ,I am providing for RestAssuredMockMvc there should be similiar configuation for MockMvc as well:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void initializeMockMvcWithControllerAdvice(Object controller, Object controllerAdvice, ContentType contentType) {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.reset();
    RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new Object[]{controller}).setControllerAdvice(new Object[]{controllerAdvice}).build());
    RestAssuredMockMvc.requestSpecification = (new MockMvcRequestSpecBuilder()).setContentType(contentType).build();
  }
```